# Why PackageScan in citrus test framework is not taking all xml testcases with the patterns that we specified

Tags: java, xml, citrus-framework

I am setting file pattern in citrus application properties like this

```
 citrus.xml.file.name.pattern=/**/*Test.xml,/**/*Rest.xml
```

but citrus was executing only filenames with extension .Test xml. It was not considering the later part of the i.e is file names with extension .Rest.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is a bug in Citrus where the first matching test of a custom pattern is not executed when using package scan option.

Further matching test files with *Rest.xml name pattern should be included then. The issue has been reported and is about to be fixed with next version: https://github.com/christophd/citrus/issues/307